# get the port no where gsm modem is connected using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, gsm

I am planning to send sms using a modem in C# from an asp.net application.As the project will be 
integrated to another project it wont be having any field for user input to enter the com port.How can i get the port number where my modem in connected from C#.

Thanks,
Sagar.

Comment: Generally these devices have a "HELO" type command that you can send to it. What I did for a magtripe reader was send the specific HELO to each COM port and stored the one that responded for the rest of the session. Your specific modem may have a specific command for this purpose, or they may be standardized (not sure.. haven't done this with GSM modems before).

Comment: Why don't just place port name into `.config` file?

Answer (score 0):

To check that a modem is connected to particular port you can send AT command into this port.
This function below returns true if we found a modem on the current COM port:

```
    private bool CheckExistingModemOnComPort(SerialPort serialPort)
    {
        if ((serialPort == null) || !serialPort.IsOpen)
            return false;

        // Commands for modem checking
        string[] modemCommands = new string[] { "AT",       // Check connected modem. After 'AT' command some modems autobaud their speed.
                                                "ATQ0" };   // Switch on confirmations
        serialPort.DtrEnable = true;    // Set Data Terminal Ready (DTR) signal 
        serialPort.RtsEnable = true;    // Set Request to Send (RTS) signal

        string answer = "";
        bool retOk = false;
        for (int rtsInd = 0; rtsInd < 2; rtsInd++)
        {
            foreach (string command in modemCommands)
            {
                serialPort.Write(command + serialPort.NewLine);
                retOk = false;
                answer = "";
                int timeout = (command == "AT") ? 10 : 20;

                // Waiting for response 1-2 sec
                for (int i = 0; i < timeout; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    answer += serialPort.ReadExisting();
                    if (answer.IndexOf("OK") >= 0)
                    {
                        retOk = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // If got responses, we found a modem
            if (retOk)
                return true;

            // Trying to execute the commands without RTS
            serialPort.RtsEnable = false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

On the next stage we can collect some data from the modem.

- **ATQ0** - switch on confirmations (receive OK on each request)
- **ATE0** - switch on echo
- **ATI** - get modem details
- **ATI3** - get extended modem details (not all modems supports this command)